How to Inject Inline Attribute Styles into an Element without style-src 'unsafe-inline' in Content Security Policy?
I'm working on a web application where I have a 3rd party hosted script that dynamically injects inline styles directly into HTML elements. I've encountered a Content Security Policy (CSP) issue related to the style-src 'unsafe-inline' directive.
Here is a simplified example of what I'm trying to achieve:
Example HTML Element added by 3rd party script:
<div id="myElement" style="color: red; font-size: 16px;">Hello, world!</div>

Example styling script from 3rd party script:
document.getElementById('myElement').style.color = 'blue';
document.getElementById('myElement').style.fontSize = '20px';

My current CSP looks like this:
default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' https://cdn.example.min.js; style-src 'self' https://cdn.example.min.js;

I understand that using 'unsafe-inline' for style-src can pose security risks, but it seems necessary.
My questions are:

What are the potential security implications of using style-src 'unsafe-inline' in my CSP, and how can I mitigate these risks?
Are there alternative methods to inject inline styles dynamically without compromising security?
If style-src 'unsafe-inline' is the only viable option, what best practices should I follow to minimize vulnerabilities?

Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I have already tried nonce values, but doesnt work as it seems to not carry through on dynamically added elements
